# How could I make all the objects resize depending on width of the browser?

Tags: html, css

When I resize the website then they are falling down below each other but I want them to still stay next to each other even if I resize the browser. Could someone have a look at this and see if there is something I can do.

All the help is welcome.

Thanks in advance.

For the people that prefer a jsfiddle demo:

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ph9geuz0/)

For the ones that prefer code on the website:

```css
#box h2 {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 26px;
  color: #888;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: left;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.text-1 {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin-right: 130px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #888;
  text-align: left;
}

.text-1 p {
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 36px;
  text-align: left;
}

#box {
  background-color: white;
  display: inline-block;
}

.first {
  width: 300;
  margin-top: 5px;
  max-height: 200px;
  box-shadow: 2px;
  float: left;
  margin: 30px;
}

.second {
  width: 300px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  max-height: 200px;
  box-shadow: 2px;
  float: left;
  margin: 30px;
}

.third {
  width: 300px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  max-height: 200px;
  box-shadow: 2px;
  float: left;
  margin: 30px;
}

.third p {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 32px;
  color: #888;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.first p {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 32px;
  color: #888;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.second p {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 32px;
  color: #888;
  font-weight: 300;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #888;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.parallax {
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url('/assets/image/parallax.jpg');
  /* Full height */
  height: 250px;
  /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <h2>Vår process</h2>
  <div class="text-1">
    <p>VI HJÄLPER DIG MED ALLT.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="first wow fadeInLeft"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/tYxVLfz/arende.png">
    <h3>KONTAKT</H3>
    <p>Kontakta oss genom telefon eller vårat kontaktformulär på hemsidan.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="second wow fadeInUp"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/tYxVLfz/arende.png">
    <H3>GRANSKAN</H3>
    <P>Vi går igenom ditt ärende och ser om vi har möjlighet och utföra jobbet.</P>
  </div>
  <div class="third wow fadeInRight"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/tYxVLfz/arende.png">
    <H3>LEVERANS</H3>
    <P>Vi kommer hem till dig och fixar det du behöver hjälp med.</P>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ph9geuz0/

Comment: If the element sizes are absolute (like they are now) you're pretty much well stuffed. If you wanted them to scale with the window, why wouldn't you just make the element sizes a percentage of the window size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using `float: left` to position the elements. What you're seeing is the expected behavior of the `float` property. Items are flushed over to the side until one can no longer fit, in which case it drops down.

I have made an updated fiddle where I removed the `float: left` styles and wrapped your `.wow` elements inside of a container. That container I have given the property `display: flex`.  The default behavior of this will set the child elements, (the `.wow` boxes) side by side and resize them accordingly as the browser also resizes. Only when you explicitly set the items to wrap, will they.

```
.container {
  display: flex;
}
```

I am not entirely sure what you're end result should look like but I threw together this fiddle in hopes it'll help out. http://jsfiddle.net/du4tyrb0/5/

You can learn more about Flexbox here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox

I hope this helps. Cheers!

Comment: This was great but i when  do this all my elements floats left and are not centered even my text. Do you have any idea of what i can do? (When fullscreen)

Comment: align-items: center;  justify-content: center;

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @AdnanCejvan I updated the fiddle. Flexbox can center its items horizontally with the justify-content: center property. This will center the boxes themselves not the content within. So I then added text-align: center to the individual boxes to center their individual content.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Bootsrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/getting-started/introduction/), [CSS grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/), [CSS Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)...; see [responsive design](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp)

Pick one and do your research.